# Where does Eclipse find javac to compile a project?

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is what I have:

JAVA_HOME=C:\Software\Java\jdk1.5.0_12 (points to JDK 5.0)

In Eclipse "Installed Runtimes" I have:
jre 1.5.0_12 (points to JRE 5.0)
jre 1.6.0_3 (points to JRE 6.0) (this one is default)

I do not have "javac" on my PATH (i.e. I cannot run javac -version from command line if I am not in JDK/bin).

My project is set to use jre 1.6.0_3 and compiler's Compliance Level is set to 6.0.

Question is: how Eclipse is able to compile my project? Where it finds a compiler for 6.0? Moreover, is there a way to tell precisely which compiler (i.e. path to javac) is used by Eclipse?

P.S. OS XP SP2 if it is relevant
P.P.S. I do not have any -vm set in eclipse.ini. In eclipse I see eclipse.vm=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll and it is still a JRE.

Comment: I had the same question =) Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325498/where-does-eclipse-find-javac-to-compile-a-project

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Eclipse has the [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php) which includes the incremental compiler so it does not need an external one unless that is your wish :)

Comment: Actually, you can't replace the incremental compiler in the JDT with javac. I suppose you can use a standard javac for headless builds, but not in the IDE.

Comment: You can use an Ant build script to have javac compile your code in Eclipse if you'd like.

Comment: that's why Eclipse IDE is Compile on Save (cos), may be.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has a list of installed JRE's under **window->preferences->java->Installed JRE's**.  The one selected as the default will be the one included with Eclipse, but you can easily add any other JRE's from this same preference pane, and select any default you wish.

This will be the system wide default, which can be overridden on a project by project basis from the Build Path->Libraries tab.  To change, select **Add Library->JRE System Library** and choose from your configured JRE's.  Then remove the library for the default.

Comment: This changes the JRE - I don't think it will make Eclipse use an external javac.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is shipped with an built-in compiler.
You can use an external JDK, if you configure it in the preferences.

Edit: Thanks to André!

Comment: That's not true, it's shipped with a compiler, but not with a jdk!