# Java: Generics handled differenlty in Eclipse and javac

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Say we have class

```
public class Entry<K, V> {
  public Entry(K k,V v) { 
    mKey = k;
    mValue = v;   
  }

  public K getKey() {
    return mKey;
  }

  public V getValue() {
    return mValue;
  }

  ...

}
```

Then we write an extending class like:

```
public class ExtendedEntry<K extends SomeSpecificKey, V> extends Entry<K, V>
```

Then, one class more in the hierarchy:

```
public class ConcreteEntry<Option extends Something, K extends MoreSpecificKey<Option>, V> extends ExtendedEntry<K, V>
```

`MoreSpecificKey` here:

```
public interface MoreSpecificKey<OptionType extends Something> extends SomeSpecificKey {
    public void doSomething(OptionType option);
}
```

And I use `doSomething()` method somewhere in the code of `ConcreteEntry`.

Then Eclipse compiler says OK and builds code and shows no warnings.

But `javac` responses:

> ...ConcreteEntry.java:6 types ...ExtendedEntry and ...ExtendedEntry are incompatible: both define getKey() method, but unrelated return types

When I change (removing generic type) `MoreSpecificKey` to:

```
public interface MoreSpecificKey extends SomeSpecificKey {
    public <OptionType extends Something> void doSomething(OptionType option);
}
```

`ConcreteEntry` definition now:

```
public class ConcreteEntry<Option extends Something, K extends MoreSpecificKey, V> extends ExtendedEntry<K, V>
```

Error in `javac` is gone, and everything is compiled OK too.

So, what's the reason Eclipse compiles code like this -- is it any compiler parameter defined or different preferences, or differences in compilers. How to handle (fix) this while developing in Eclipse and be sure that it will compile in `javac`.

Comment: You haven't shown how `Entry` is related to anything else.  I assume that `ExtendedEntry` is meant to extend `Entry`, but that's not shown in the code you've posted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

part of this is already explained in the Question [Where does Eclipse find javac to compile a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325498/587642) - Eclipse uses a different compiler

Comment: Yes, there is an option to monitor the way it builds in both ways with `jconsole` and use `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`. I'll try it now.