# javac error: inconvertible types with generics?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, javac

There are several other SO questions talking about generics compiling OK w/ Eclipse's compiler but not javac (i.e. [Java: Generics handled differenlty in Eclipse and javac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4133800/587642) and [Generics compiles and runs in Eclipse, but doesn't compile in javac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2858799/587642)) -- however this looks like a slightly different one.

I have an `enum` class:

```
public class LogEvent {
   public enum Type {
       // ... values here ...
   }
   ...
}
```

and I have another class with a method that takes in arbitrary objects of types descended from `Enum`:

```
@Override public <E extends Enum<E>> void postEvent(
    Context context, E code, Object additionalData) 
{
    if (code instanceof LogEvent.Type)
    {
        LogEvent.Type scode = (LogEvent.Type)code;
    ...
```

This works fine in Eclipse, but when I do a clean built with `ant`, I am getting a pair of errors, one on the `instanceof` line, the other on the casting line:

```
443: inconvertible types
    [javac] found   : E
    [javac] required: mypackage.LogEvent.Type
    [javac]         if (code instanceof LogEvent.Type)
    [javac]             ^

445: inconvertible types
    [javac] found   : E
    [javac] required: com.dekaresearch.tools.espdf.LogEvent.Type
    [javac]             LogEvent.Type scode = (LogEvent.Type)code;
    [javac]                                                  ^
```

Why does this happen, and how can I get around this problem so it will compile properly?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know why it's happening, but a workaround is easy:

```
@Override public <E extends Enum<E>> void postEvent(
    Context context, E code, Object additionalData) 
{
    Object tmp = code;
    if (tmp instanceof LogEvent.Type)
    {
        LogEvent.Type scode = (LogEvent.Type)tmp;
    ...
```

It's ugly, but it works...

Comment: thanks. Why is that ugly? It's simple and has low runtime cost.

Comment: @Jason S: It's ugly because I can't see why it's required.

Comment: This is a known bug, IIRC. Actually, there dozens of related bugs with none of them fixed yet.

Comment: I was about to throw myself out of the window ( hey I'm at ground floor :)
Thanks a lot for this one... And the worst I think I've already been fighting for this one few years ago

Comment: I think this is the bug (or one of them): http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6932571

Comment: The key is to assign to an `Object` before the cast. That avoids triggering the bug. Thanks @JonSkeet!

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps it is because you've declared E as something that extends Enum<E>. I can't say I understand it completely, but it looks like it limits the set of types to some subset that can't include LogEvent.Type for some reason. Or maybe it's just a bug in the compiler. I'd be happy if someone could explain it more clearly, but here is what you can do:

```
public <E extends Enum<?>> void postEvent(E code) 
{
    if (code instanceof LogEvent.Type)
    {
        LogEvent.Type scode = (LogEvent.Type)code;
        ...
    }
    ...
```

This works and it is more elegant than just casting to an Object.

Comment: it works because "E extends Enum<E>" refers to some specific subclass of Enum (which may not be compatible with LogEvent.Type).  whereas "E extends Enum<?>" refers to any class which extends Enum, of which LogEvent.Type is a valid possibility.

Comment: @jtahlborn: The `E extends Enum<E>` is standard boilerplate for any class that properly extends Enum, which all `enum` classes do, and `LogEvent.Type` is an `enum` class, so it should work as well, but there seems to be a bug in `javac`.

Comment: @jtahlborn, yes, think of it - does LogEvent.Type extend Enum<LogEvent.Type>? Surely it does. But it's exactly what we mean when we write "E extends Enum<E>", with E = LogEvent.Type. So I agree that it looks like a bug in javac. In fact, "E extends Enum<?>" and "E extends Enum<E>" should mean exactly the same thing because any enum type E can only extend Enum<E> and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and upgraded from jdk1.6.0_16 to jdk1.6.0_23 and it went away without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `instanceof` both operands have to inherit/implement the same class/interface.
E just can't be cast to LogEvent.Type

I don't know what your full method looks like, but this should solve your issue by using interfaces and not Generics.

```
public interface EventType { }
public class LogEvent  {
    public enum Type implements EventType {}
}

public void postEvent(Context context, EventType code, Object additionalData) {
    if(code instanceof LogEvent.Type) {
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want Enum to be the base type, not EventType. I need my method to accept arbitrary Enum values.

Comment: But why E can't be cast to LogEvent.Type? E is a subclass of Enum, and LogEvent.Type is a subclass of Enum as well. I understand that the problem part is that it's not just Enum, but Enum<E>, I just can't understand what that means exactly.

Comment: The other SO questions on this topic seem to indicate that `javac` has a known bug with recursive generic bounds, so maybe it gets confused. With respect to the `<E extends Enum<E>>`, if you haven't seen it before: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106