# capture#XXX in error message (Java Generics)

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

My apologies for a silly question; just cannot come up with a proper term to search for. Trying to compile a third-party sources, I've bumped into the following compilation error:

```
/Users/alf/Work/concise.svn/ExtendedSet/src/it/uniroma3/mat/extendedset/transactions/PairSet.java:[230,28] inconvertible types
found   : java.util.Collection<capture#741 of ? extends it.uniroma3.mat.extendedset.transactions.Pair<XT,XI>>
required: it.uniroma3.mat.extendedset.transactions.PairSet<XT,XI>
```

I guess I know what is the problem—but what does `capture#741` mean? Each time I'm trying to recompile, the number after `#` changes—not sure if it helps in any way.

Update:

The code in question was,

```
public static <XT, XI> PairSet<XT, XI> newPairSet(Collection<? extends Pair<XT, XI>> ps, boolean compressed) {
    if (ps instanceof PairSet)
        return (PairSet<XT, XI>) ps;
```

and the fix suggested in [javac error: inconvertible types with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829576/javac-error-inconvertible-types-with-generics) works just fine—but what does `capture#741` mean?

Comment: The capture#xxx is the placeholder for the `?` if you use `PairSet<?,?>`. I think you try to cast to a type parameter that is incompatible with the actual type parameter.

Comment: @Stephan -- could you post that as an answer rather than a comment? Then maybe alf could accept it and this question would come off the unanswered list.

Comment: @Stephan - confirmed, will be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture#xxx is the placeholder for the generic type argument `?` if you use `PairSet<?,?>`. I think you try to cast to a type parameter that is incompatible with the actual type parameter.

If you do not know the actual type argument, you can cast to `PairSet` and cast to XT or XI later.