# Setting compiler in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used the OpenJDK to modify the  Java compiler to display additional warnings. Now I want to use this compiler in Eclipse.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325498/where-does-eclipse-find-javac-to-compile-a-project) answer Eclipse uses an incremental compiler. Is there a way to disable the incremental compiler and set a path to my custom compiler? Would this be able with a plugin?

Alternatively if this was not possible, how can you build Eclipse on your own?

Comment: You can't change the 'compiler' that the Eclipse Java editor uses as it is very tightly integrated with the editor. You can disable automatic builds and use something like maven to build with your compiler - but that won't be shown in the editor.

Comment: @deHaar You can only set the runtime environment that way, but not the compiler

Comment: @greg-449 You sure can, it is open source and I have enough time for it ;)

Comment: By 'change' I mean just switching to a 'javac' type compiler. The Eclipse editor makes extensive use of the [JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html). You can, of course, modify the JDT source. Eclipse GIT repositories are at https://git.eclipse.org/c/

Comment: @greg-449 I thought about that already, but I didn't find a guide on how to build Eclipse completely after I edited the JDT (see my last question).

Comment: @BlobbyBob Totally right, thanks. I'll remove my inappropriate comment.

Comment: Which part of the Java compiler did you modified? Are you looking for the errors in the abstract syntax tree generated by the compiler or in a later step when the bytecode is generated?

Comment: To answer your last question: Eclipse can be built e. g. by the Eclipse IDE or headless by the Maven extension Tycho (which is used by the Eclipse project itself, e. g. [JDT](https://ci.eclipse.org/jdt/)).

Comment: @howlger After parsing I analyze the AST for certain rules (PMD style). Where do I get the Maven build script from (link)?

Comment: @GhostCat I didn't accept answers, because they are not sufficient/not helpful for the question. You can improve the following aspects: 1. JDT/The eclipse compiler is not _baked_ into eclipse, since eclipse has a modular design (see   [this](https://sreenathonline.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/xarchitecture10-pagespeed-ic-ab1x9dct2x.png)) 2. Workarounds are no solution 3. The correct answer is: Write a plugin using the JDT CompilationParticipant extension point, which isn't the main part of your answer.

Comment: OK, fine with me ... maybe you write up a more detailed self answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incremental eclipse compiler is part of the JDT module. Disabling it will also disable features like syntax highlighting, that you probably don't want to miss.

However you can use a plugin to modify the incremental compiler in the JDT using the [`compilationParticipant`](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_core_compilationParticipant.html&cp=3_1_1_4) extension point. You can place your own code in the various compilation steps with this approach.

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know this extension point. You should only be careful not to calculate time-consuming things here for performance reasons. It would be nice if you could publish your work as open source.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments given by greg-449: to my knowledge, the compiler that is used to give you syntax highlighting and warnings within the eclipse editor window is *baked* into eclipse. Beyond that, eclipse JDT provides extension points which *might* allow you to do some of things you have in mind. See their [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_int.htm) for further details.

Still, my distinct non-answer: don't do that. Don't invent your own tool chain elements to improve code quality. They will only work for you, and your special eclipse setup.

Instead: look into existing tooling to give you what you want, as in

- Eclipse allows you to [enable](https://www.eclipse.org/tm/development/compiler_warnings.php) many warnings/errors that default javac doesn't provide
- IntelliJ goes even way beyond that. You have tons and tons of "inspections" available with that IDE
- Consider looking in static code analysis tools, such as PMD or findbugs

Comment: The warnings/errors from your first point sound interesting, I could maybe add my own custom warnings at this spot. Is this possible with a plugin or do I need to modify the Eclipse source?

Comment: @BlobbyBob Eclipse JDT provides numerous extension points that plugins can use - for example `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CompilationParticipant` is told about various build steps and can add errors. See the JDT Plugin Developers Guide in the Eclipse Help.

Answer (score 1):

The incremental Eclipse compiler is a core component of Eclipse and therefore not easy to modify or replace. The **abstract syntax tree (AST)** is not only used to compile source code to bytecod and find errors in this process but also for code highlighting, navigation, searching, refactoring, etc.

**In Eclipse the abstract syntax tree is public API** and can be **created without modifying or replacing the compiler**: see [Eclipse help - JDT Plug-in Developer Guide - Manipulating Java code](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm).

Alternatively, you can **add your rules in [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io)** which can be seen as the successor of FindBugs. SpotBugs reads bytecode (not source code) and creates an AST based on [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) (which has a different AST API than Eclipse or the OpenJDK compiler). The advantage of using SpotBugs would be that you would not need to implement the displaying of the found bugs and other UI things yourself.

To also answer your last question (which is not relevant if you are using Eclipse's public AST API or SpotBugs): Eclipse can be built e. g. by the Eclipse IDE or headless by the Maven extension Tycho (which is used by the Eclipse project itself, e. g. [by JDT via Jenkins](https://ci.eclipse.org/jdt/) based on this [`pom.xml`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/pom.xml)).